# Proper Syntax for catching C++ input mismatch (String instead of int)

Tags: c++, try-catch

What would be the proper syntax of catching input mismatch in this situation:

```
void getMonthlyBudget(fstream& budgetFile, int months)
{
    MonthlyBudget mb;
    int count = 1;

    budgetFile.open("budget.bin", ios::out|ios::binary);
    if(budgetFile.fail())
    {
      cout<<"Could not find file: budget.bin \n";
      system("PAUSE"); 
    }

    try
    {
        do
        {
            cout<<"Enter your housing budget for month "<<count<<":\n";
            cin>>mb.housing;
            cout<<"Enter your utilities budget for month "<<count<<":\n";
            cin>>mb.utilites;
            cout<<"Enter your household expense budget for month "<<count<<":\n";
            cin>>mb.houseHold;
            cout<<"Enter your transportation budget for month "<<count<<":\n";
            cin>>mb.transportation;
            cout<<"Enter your food budget for month "<<count<<":\n";
            cin>>mb.food;
            cout<<"Enter your medical budget for month "<<count<<":\n";
            cin>>mb.medical;
            cout<<"Enter your insurance budget for month "<<count<<":\n";
            cin>>mb.insurance;
            cout<<"Enter your entertainment budget for month "<<count<<":\n";
            cin>>mb.entertainment;
            cout<<"Enter your clothing budget for month "<<count<<":\n";
            cin>>mb.clothinng;
            cout<<"Enter your Miscellaneous budget for month "<<count<<":\n";
            cin>>mb.misc;

            budgetFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&mb),sizeof(mb));
            count++;
            months --;
        }while(months != 0);
    }

    catch(...)
    {
        cin.clear(); 
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        cout<<"Error, invalid input entered.";
    }
```

The following output when the program catches input mismatch can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt0fO.png). I'm assuming the enter key is being picked up in this situation.

Comment: _"assuming"_ Problem number one right there!

Comment: What happens is, the stream has its `failbit` set (so that `fail()` returns true). Once that bit is set, all subsequent input operations fail immediately, without even attempting to extract any characters from the string. Streams don't normally throw exceptions on failure, but if you want them to, you can call `cin.exceptions(std::ios::failbit)` before you start reading. After this call, whenever `failbit` is set on `cin`, an exception of type `std::ios_base::failure` is thrown.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Seriously, once more, _please write your answers in the answer section_. You are bypassing every single quality control measure this site has. Hover your mouse over the "add a comment" link and read what it says.